# AWS with flask (port channel)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I have an AWS instance running. Serving through a SimpleHTTPServer works.

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXX ~]$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 ...
p54A5C877.dip0.t-XXX.org - - [07/Mar/2013 12:36:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But then with flask, somehow the request does not channel through.

```
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> 
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> 
>>> @app.route('/')
... def hello_world():
...     return 'Hello World!'
... 
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':    
...     app.run(port=8080)
... 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ => no request catched
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After puzzling about this for quite some time, by chance I have found the solution 1 min after posting. Host has to be 0.0.0.0

```
app.run(port=8080,host='0.0.0.0')
```